# Ideas for speeding up greek calculations

Tags: option-pricing, greeks, python, calculation, time

My current calculations using the [vollib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/vollib/) library averages 0.5 seconds. Is there any way to get it faster? Any tips/best practice notes will be helpful. 
This is for a scripting language such as python.

See documentation here: http://vollib.org/html/apidoc/vollib.black_scholes_merton.greeks.html#module-vollib.black_scholes_merton.greeks.numerical

Comment: Can you describe your calculations in more detail, how many Greeks are you calculating? Could you show your current set-up?

Comment: If you are re-calculating very frequently (in real time), you might use the last solution as the starting point for 1 iterative step (or a few) to get the next value (what is called Iterative Refinement in linear algebra).

Comment: @Bob Jansen Calculating 10 greeks (5 put, 5 call) and 2 implied volatility (1 put, 1 call): delta, theta, vega, gamma, rho and implied volatility. current setup is just calling these functions from the library directly. In each greek calculation I called implied volatility function for the sigma input (see [documentation](http://vollib.org/html/apidoc/vollib.black_scholes_merton.greeks.html#module-vollib.black_scholes_merton.greeks.numerical)). Could this be what's slowing it down?

Comment: Try profiling your code with CProfile and identify bottlenecks. If the overhead is not due to lib, but the way you call it - try to get it improved (maybe even by cythonizing it)